# File size limit exceeded (core dumped) PHP CLI error

Tags: apache, centos, cpanel, error-logging

CentOS with Cpanel/WHM installed ("dedicated server").
HDD has 110G available.

This is a command line php error. I cannot find an error log. The specified error log is recording http errors but not CLI errors. HELP.

I've found some information that suggests that there is a log file somewhere that has exceeded 2GB.

I'm looking all over for it and can't find it.

Weird thing:
ran the command in my public_html folder and got the error message in my question title:

```
File size limit exceeded (core dumped)
```

But when I ran it inside `/var` I got:

```
File size limit exceeded
```

That's weird because I used absolute paths in the command.

`var/log` has nothing bigger than a few MB. `/tmp` has nothing bigger than about 0.7G.

I can't find this file and I can't even find an error log to give me a hint. I foud the apache access log but no error log.

EDIT:

I never found the existing log file, but I just created a new one. It successfully logged errors from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I've come up with my own answer.

I used this to find large files on the system. Ran it from the root directory.

```
/ # find -maxdepth 6 -type f -size +1G > ~/largefiles.txt
```

Surprisingly, it only took a minute or two and the results added up to less than a page.

Sure enough, I found a system.log file, located in a subdirectory of one of the siteroots, and it was exactly 2.0GB in size. I truncated it like so:

```
# > system.log
```

And now my command is working!